# accepts_nested_attributes - ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple model that each event has many forexes. I am trying to create a nested form to create new event with a bunch of forexes in a go.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forexes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :forexes

end


class Forex < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

The schema is like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180505093823) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "base"
  end

  create_table "forexes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.float    "rate"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "forexes", ["event_id"], name: "index_forexes_on_event_id"

end
```

And then I tried to create new objects using the following code in rails console. It fails.

```
Event.new( name: "11", base: "HKD", forexes_attributes: [ {code: "RMB", rate:1}, {code: "CNY",rate:2}])
```

It throws me back with this error.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'forexes_attributes' for Event.
```

I know this is quite a basic question. And I have tried many different ways after researching in different places. I couldn't debug it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try to stop spring and restart a server? `spring stop && rails s`

Comment: No I havn't. But it works.! thank you Vasilisa.

Comment: You are welcome! This command often helps with weird errors :)

Answer (score -1):

In your Event controller you need to include the forexes_attributes in event_params method as along with default one

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(forexes_attributes: Forexes_attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
end
```

Comment: if the problem was in `event_params`, then there would be no error - it would be just 'unpermitted parameter` in log

Comment: 'unpermitted parameter' error occurs when  " params.require(:event).permit(forexes_attributes: Forexes_attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
" is not properly set for nested attributes